# Angular Mat Table sort doesn't work when I put two let

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

The table dosn't want to sort when i have two "let".

Here is the code :

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Matricule">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Matricule </th>

    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let engin of enginservice.enginsListe">
    <td
        *ngIf="element.DureeContrat && element.DateFinContrat && element.DateEntree && element.LieuUtilisation && element.DateSignatureIrrijardin && element.NumContrat && element.PrestataireLocation && element.TypeEngin && element.DateSignaturePrestataire && element.DateCirculation && element.PrixLoyer && engin.IdContrat == element.IdContrat && element.DateSortie">
        {{engin.Matricule}}</td>
</ng-container>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

the "engin.Matricule" doesn't sort, I don't know how to do it, other element with only one "let" can sort.

Thank you in advance